# Youtube playlist insert API Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, xmlhttprequest, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to make web-client where you are able to add videos to playlist. Currently I have no clue what is wrong so help is more than welcome.

I get error code 400() and checked error codes, but one thing is sure that video is not on playlist. And same exact thing works in their "Try it!" section. So I think my config variable is not correct or im sending it wrong way.

```
function addSongYTPlaylist(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&part=snippet&key=AIzaSyA17v8PuNBsIwgbxg6D78iHV-w7_dYyXPw";

    var config = {
     "snippet": {
      "playlistId": {PLAYLIST_ID},
      "resourceId": {
       "videoId": {VIDEO_ID},
       "kind": "youtube#video"
      }
     }
    }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
           console.log(response);
       }
   };

   console.log(url);
   xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN});
   xmlhttp.send(config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.api.CommonRequestError), you can find the different error codes and their description in YouTube API.

The error code `400 badRequest` that you get means that your request is missing a required parameter. And the message that you received is **"No filter selected. Expected one of: playlistId, id"**.

So you need to provide playlistId or Id in order for it to work.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PL889BDECC517358C9&key=AIzaSyA17v8PuNBsIwgbxg6D78iHV-w7_dYyXPw
```

Also for more information you can check the [documention](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) of PlaylistItems: insert.